# How do I pass a string with one or more embedded new line codes?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm maintaining a function that creates an element on the DOM with the `onclick` event‡ set to a parameter passed to the function. It works very similarly to this:

```
var msg="Hi there\nGood to see you",
    returnElement=function(message) {
        document.getElementById("manipulate_me").innerHTML='<span onClick="alert(\''+message+'\');">click me and I throw a JavaScript error</span>';
    };
```

On an HTML page including `<div id="manipulate_me">Gets replaced</div>`, executing `returnElement(msg);` results in this error ([see for yourself on the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/HetQD/](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/HetQD/)):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

When I inspect the DOM, I see this (notice the new line within the `alert()`):

```
<span onclick="alert('Hi there
Good to see you');">click me and I throw a JavaScript error</span>
```

How do I pass a string with one or more embedded new line codes?

Caveats:

- I'm working on a closed system that's recently upgraded to IE8.
- Because this template is used throughout the system, augmenting the code with jQuery is not possible

‡-I know, I know--"*maintaining*", not "writing"

Comment: It's almost like I want the opposite of `eval()`

Comment: Try closing your `span` tag (not with the `</click>` you have now.

Comment: @putvande -- thanks. That was an error in my example, since corrected. It's not, alas, the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply double-escape the `\n` to accomplish this:

```
var msg="Hi there\nGood to see you\nAlways a pleasure",
    returnElement=function(message) {
        document.getElementById("manipulate_me").innerHTML='<span onClick="alert(\''+message.split("\n").join("\\n")+'\')+'\');">click me and I throw a JavaScript error</span>';
    };

returnElement(msg);
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HetQD/15/

Comment: In case that the `msg` content is unpredictable, you can use `msg.replace("\n", "\\n")` too.

Comment: @DarkAshelin Or `message.split("\n").join("\\n")+'\')`